# i was trying to make a loop that triggers if the input is not an int with the exept valueerror

Tags: python

```
   nombre=str
    while nombre==str:
     try:
      nombre=int(input("give an integer"))
     except ValueError:
      print("give a number")
      nombre=int(input("give an integer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Setting `nombre = str` doesn't seem right, because `str` is a type and the idea is for `nombre` to eventually be an instance of an actual number.
- You don't need to repeat yourself inside the loop, as long as the failure results in the `while` condition remaining true.

I think this will work:

```
from typing import Optional

nombre: Optional[int] = None
while nombre is None:
    try:
        nombre=int(input("give an integer"))
    except ValueError:
        print("that's not a valid integer, try again?")
assert nombre is not None
```

Comment: `typing` seems like massive overkill here

Comment: agree to disagree.  `python` without `mypy` is just `thon-my`.